# Как поместить несколько функций в одну в js?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть множество одинаковых функций, в которых отличается лишь id элемента. Можно ли каким-либо образом все эти функции поместить в одной?Пыталась создать цикл, но безуспешно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Передайте фукции объект к которому применяется изменение display как параметр.

Comment: и никто не ругается, что код картинкой)

Answer (score 2):

Для каждой btn нужно уметь получать соответствующую modal. Сделать это можно как в JavaScript-е, так и через дата-атрибуты в HTML.

С data-атрибутом это может быть так:

```js
var buttonIds = ["btn1", "btn2", "btn3"];

for (var buttonId of buttonIds) {
  var button = document.getElementById(buttonId);
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var modalId = this.dataset.modalId;
    var modal = document.getElementById(modalId);
    modal.style.display = "block";
  });
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="btn1" type="button" value="btn1" data-modal-id="modal1" />
<input id="btn2" type="button" value="btn2" data-modal-id="modal2" />
<input id="btn3" type="button" value="btn3" data-modal-id="modal3" />
<div id="modal1" class="modal">Modal 1</div>
<div id="modal2" class="modal">Modal 2</div>
<div id="modal3" class="modal">Modal 3</div>
```

---

Если все btn-ы можно получить не через список id-шников, а, например, через класс, то тогда код будет несколько проще:

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

for (var button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var modalId = this.dataset.modalId;
    var modal = document.getElementById(modalId);
    modal.style.display = "block";
  });
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input class="button" type="button" value="btn1" data-modal-id="modal1" />
<input class="button" type="button" value="btn2" data-modal-id="modal2" />
<input class="button" type="button" value="btn3" data-modal-id="modal3" />
<div id="modal1" class="modal">Modal 1</div>
<div id="modal2" class="modal">Modal 2</div>
<div id="modal3" class="modal">Modal 3</div>
```

---

А при использовании jQuery второй вариант можно написать ещё короче:

```js
$(".button").on("click", function() {
  var modalId = $(this).data("modalId");
  $("#" + modalId).show();
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input class="button" type="button" value="btn1" data-modal-id="modal1" />
<input class="button" type="button" value="btn2" data-modal-id="modal2" />
<input class="button" type="button" value="btn3" data-modal-id="modal3" />
<div id="modal1" class="modal">Modal 1</div>
<div id="modal2" class="modal">Modal 2</div>
<div id="modal3" class="modal">Modal 3</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Что бы не "колхозить" массив id кнопок можно сделать так: `const btns = [...document.querySelectorAll("[id*='btn']")]`

Comment: @Swartex а вдруг есть `btnSend`, которая используется для другого... В таких случаях, на мой взгляд, лучше всего опираться на класс (или что-то аналогичное), который используют все кнопки и только они

Comment: все возможно :) я просто написал комент из вашего ответа выше. Что бы не пилить массив идишников)

Comment: @Swartex это да. Но у автора id-шники совсем разные - там вообще без шансов

Answer (score 1):

```js
const ids = [
  {modalId: 'myModal', btnId: 'myBtn'},
  {modalId: 'semia1', btnId: 'semia'}
]

function linkBtnAndModal(idsArray) {
  idsArray.forEach(item => {
    const modal = document.getElementById(item.modalId);
    const btn = document.getElementById(item.btnId);
    
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
       modal.style.display = 'block';
    });
  });
};

linkBtnAndModal(ids);
```

```html
<div id="myModal" style="display: none;">myModal</div>
<button id="myBtn">myBtn</button>

<div id="semia1" style="display: none;">semia1</div>
<button id="semia">semia1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще 1 вариант, который не предусматривает навешивание кучи обработчиков

```js
const list = {
   myBtn:"myModal",
   semia: "semia1"
}
window.onclick =  (e) => {
   const key= e.target.id;
   if (list[key]){
     const id = list[key];
     const modal = document.getElementById(id);
     modal.style.display = "block"
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" style="display: none;">myModal</div>
<button id="myBtn">myBtn</button>

<div id="semia1" style="display: none;">semia1</div>
<button id="semia">semia1</button>

<div id="qwerty" style="display: none;">myModal</div>
<button>qwwwBtn</button>
```